# Section elements not resizing/keeping format to different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

For the life of me I cannot get these section elements to be responsive. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I think it may have to do with my media queries.

Any ideas? Or maybe I just have no idea what I'm doing when I thought I did. Quite possible!

```css
<style>
 section.kppr{
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin: -6% 0 0 0;
      float: center;
    }
  
   .kppr p{
      font-size: 420%;
      color: #89d4e8;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  
  .kppr img{
       max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     width: auto;
  }
  
   .twgb{
      width: 14%;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 0 0 20%;
    }
  
  .twgb p{
   line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4% 0 0 0;
    font-size: 115%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  
  .descript{
     text-align: left;
  }
  
  .descript p{
     line-height: 120%;
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 1% 0 0 0;
    
  }
  
  .discount img{
   float: left;
    padding: 0 1%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  /*--------------------MEDIA!!!---------------*/
  @media screen and (max-width: 478px){
        body{
            position: absolute;
        }   
    }
  
   @media screen and (max-width: 740px){
     section{
      position: absolute;
     }
     section.kppr{
          float: left;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
     
     section.twgb{
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
     
     section.descript{
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
  
     section.discount{
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
   }
  
</style>
```

```html
<section class="kppr">
 <p>kids play <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/5759e5882b8ddea12fed577b/1465509256880/STL-Home-Heart.png" alt="kids play parents relax" /> parents relax</p>
</section>

<section class="twgb">
  <p><font color="#000">together we</font><br><font color="#89d4e8" size="6%">give back</font></p>
</section>

<section class="discount">
 <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/5759f17507eaa0ecb82b3677/1465512309355/STL-Home-5.png" alt="5% given back" />
</section>

<section class="descript">
 <p> of every dollar goes back to helping children <br>in foster care find safe and loving homes.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. plz remove position:absolute from body

   @media screen and (max-width: 478px){
         body{
               position: absolute;
           }
       }

2.plz remove position:absolute from section

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 740px){
         section{
            position: absolute;
         }
}
```

3.in @media screen and (max-width: 740px), add **section.kppr** to 
  float:none; & margin-top:-6%;. (-6% ?)

4.in @media screen and (max-width: 740px), **section.twgb**, **section.descript** & **section.discount** to
  add float:none; & text-align:center; .

5.in @media screen and (max-width: 740px), add this code to

```
**section.discount img**{
         float:none;
         }
```

sorry for bad English :(

Comment: That makes it look way better and much more manageable. Thank you a ton! I can use this for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

So you're already using percentages in your CSS, so remove all of your @media CSS and tell me how that looks to you.

Comment: It looks better, it's not floating down and disappearing underneath my other content on the page now. Here's a screen shot of how it looks on mobile. https://gyazo.com/fc85e7770a28d5d9479bd4858f375fad here is how I want it to look. I want it to retain it's form, just decrease in size with the screen https://gyazo.com/9b74cc04b5207bcb2ed20315696139f0

Comment: I was able to get to this: https://jsfiddle.net/08r5h0v0/14/ It eliminates all of the @media and uses vw for font size so it relies on the user screen. The only way to truly get the same size for all elements in the lower section would be to create an image with text in it and then place the image in your html. Otherwise, the responsiveness will cause some odd paragraph structures when viewed on different screens.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot wrong here, it seems to me. So much so that you might need to be considerably more specific about what you what to achieve regarding "responsiveness", which is a vague term rather than a description of a specific behaviour. I can give you a few tips that will at least highlight where you might be confused.

- `float` has no `center` value. Fortunately setting it probably won't
  cause any problems.
- Using `position: absolute` on `body` likely isn't having the effect you're expecting, and typically isn't something you'd want to do, if I'm not mistaken. If declaring `body` as a positional parent was necessary I'd suggest using `position: relative` instead, but given that body is one of the ultimate parents of the document anyway, everything will already be position relative to it.
- You're also applying `position: absolute` to your `section` elements, but as with `body` you haven't specified any positions (`top|right|bottom|left`). Because you've got `body` set to `absolute` the sections that become `absolute` will adhere to `body` with little regard to the other objects on the page, causing effects you probably weren't hoping for. You might be confused about the relationship between `position` and `float`, where in fact that isn't really one at all.
- You're floating elements which are also being set to 100% width, which probably isn't having the effect you're expecting, and will in fact simply cause all the content of those containers to behave almost as if they aren't in containers at all. Floating is usually applied to objects which are narrower than the parent, allowing them to cause other inline or floating objects to wrap around them.

You might consider revising your interpretation of the term "responsive". I could argue that what you have is responsive because stuff responds to the size of the screen; it just doesn't look very good. You could achieve responsiveness in a wide variety of ways, you just need to know what layout you're after on smaller screens, and figure out how to change the styles you have for one size of screen to achieve the layout you want for others.

Comment: I'm wanting it to have this appearance --> I should have clarified more. I want it to keep the format it has, I just want it to decrease in size as the screen compresses https://gyazo.com/9b74cc04b5207bcb2ed20315696139f0 thank you for the additional information about the relationships between float and position, I have never known that before.